# Plot number of overexposed pixels per column in grey scale image

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, performance-tuning, image-processing

I have a grey scale image (1600*480 pixels, 8 bit): https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4f1m.png (update)

I want to determine the number of overexposed pixels in each column.
Then I want to plot the a combined plot which is containing the image and the plot showing the number of overexposed pixels together with a smoothed curve.

*Is this the right way how I did it? Can something be improved/corrected?*

```
dim = ImageDimensions[image];

xaxis = Range[dim[[1]]];

overexposedPixelsPerColumn = 
  Count[Flatten@
      Values[ComponentMeasurements[
        ImageTake[image, {1, dim[[2]]}, {#, #}], "IntensityData"]], 
     brightness_ /; brightness == 1.] & /@ Range[dim[[1]]];

totalOverexposedPixels = Total@overexposedPixelsPerColumn;

maxOverexposedPixelsPerColumn = Max@overexposedPixelsPerColumn;

nPoints = 50;

smoothedOverexposedPixelsPerColumn = 
  MovingAverage[overexposedPixelsPerColumn, nPoints];

Show[
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xaxis, overexposedPixelsPerColumn}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1, PlotStyle -> {LightGray}, 
   Epilog -> {{PointSize[Large], 
      Point[Transpose[{xaxis, overexposedPixelsPerColumn}]]}, 
     Inset[image, Scaled[{.5, 1}], Automatic, Scaled[1]]}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"# of overexposed pixels per column", 
      ""}, {"column", 
      StringJoin["red curve: moving average over ", ToString[nPoints],
        " pixels", "; total # of overexposed pixels=", 
       ToString[totalOverexposedPixels]]}}, 
   PlotRange -> {All, 
     MinMax@(overexposedPixelsPerColumn) + {0, 
       Floor@(0.4*maxOverexposedPixelsPerColumn)}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 35, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> 2000, 
   ImagePadding -> {{All, All}, {All, 50}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, AxesStyle -> Thick, 
   FrameStyle -> Thick],
  ListLinePlot[
   Transpose[{xaxis[[nPoints/2 ;; Length@xaxis - nPoints/2]], 
     smoothedOverexposedPixelsPerColumn}], 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsoluteThickness[3]}]
   ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to assess `"IntensityData"` from `ComponentsMeasurements` because I failed to find anything but a small entry in details section about it.

My comment was only slightly off, since `Binarize` treats the second parameter inclusively, that is `1.` means anything `<=1.` will be `0` then the result is a black image. To exclude `1.` we can flip it with `ColorNegate`:

```
img = Import @ "https://i.imgur.com/lPdFDcm.png";

data = Total /@ 
    Transpose @ ImageData@ColorNegate@Binarize[ColorNegate@img, 0.] // N;
data // Total

ListPlot[
 data, AspectRatio -> 1/3, ImageSize -> 600
]
```

[image]

Let me know if I made a mistake and I will delete the answer. If you find it more trustworthy I will try to update it later.

Comment: What confuses me `Dimensions[data]` is `1413` instead of `1600`. Ah, I see I uploaded the png file directly from the notebook with wrong size. I have now uploaded the one with 1600*480 pixels, see the link `https://i.imgur.com/BqgJRv7.png`. Sorry for the mistake. If I now use your code with this image it produces exactly what I got, when I use `ListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1/3, ImageSize -> 600, PlotRange -> All]`. Thank you for the solution. May be you can update your solution with the new file ...